# Cannot format or remove "extra" partitions on HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I have a 500GB Seagate Laptop HDD that I received from a scrapped laptop that I am trying to format. I managed to format one of the partitions but cannot remove or format the remaining ones.

Here is a view of the HDD in the Windows Disk Management Utility.
[image]

When I right click on any of the partitions except the F: partition I get the context menu with only one option "help".

Any idea how I can remove the other partitions and format the entire drive?

Comment: Have you gotten all the data out? Would running a livecd  and something like dban or shred be an option?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't my laptop. I was just trying to do it without outside softwares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what you need to do is "clean" the disk. Open an elevated command prompt. Click Start and type in cmd and right click on that and click Run as Administrator. Now type in `diskpart` and hit enter.

Type in `list disk` and you will get an output of the hard drives and flash drives you have. Then type in `select disk #` # being the number of the disk you want to wipe. After that type in `clean`. This will wipe the entire disk.

Answer (score 1):

### C: is the boot partition

After Windows 10 upgrade there were eight partitions.  Booted into a Live USB Linux and run `gparted`, then simply deleted **all** partitions except the required EFI partition and C: partition, and even shrunk the C: partition to make room for a dual boot later.  (Note: did not move the C: partition, just shrunk it.)

[image: Disk Management]

At reboot, Windows 10 started just fine with just the two partitions.  I even forgot and did a hybrid Windows shutdown before all this (where it saves state to speed next startup) so it started fine but showed all those old partitions for a while, crashed on disk management rescan, but next full start it was okay from then on, after making me do a diskcheck.  Feels quite stable to delete all but EFI and C: when your C: is your boot partition.

Reference [reserved partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) being deletable, and [efi partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) being required.

### C: is NOT the boot partition

I repeated the above on a different system where the vendor (Acer) booted from a special partition first, which wasn't my EFI or C: partitions, and Windows wouldn't start any longer, because I deleted the special vendor boot partition.  Note, it did boot Windows (EFI partition worked) but couldn't find C: and had a Windows 10 version of a blue screen which is lighter blue and some sort of error about no boot partition found.

Ordinarily to fix this boot your Windows 10 recovery USB stick then pick: language `US` | `troubleshoot` | `advanced options` | `startup repair` | `Windows 10`.  Except this wouldn't help because the vendor tweaked the EFI and C: partitions to not be fixable.

My fix was to boot Windows 10 recovery USB, take the options that lead you to a command prompt.  There, you can try with the usual `bootsect /nt60 C:` and look for Windows installations `bootrec /scanos` and mine found none.  Then ran `diskpart`, did the usual `list volumes` mine happened to be 2, `select volume 3`, `remove letter C`, `select volume 2`, `assign letter C`, to make C: where Windows is installed (it's temporary).

It showed as hidden, so to unhide it couldn't simply use `attribute volume`, got a not found, ended up having to `set id=ebd0a0a2-...etc` to make it a normal Data partition, then changed the attribute to not hidden.  Running `attribute volume` should show "no" on all four lines.  At that point, C: is not hidden.  Had to `attribute volume clear nodefaultdriveletter` so on boot it would assign C: normally.  Just for grins, changed the EFI partition to be an EFI partition (happened to be 1) with `select volume 1` and `set id=c12a7328...etc`.  Still shows hidden but that's okay, EFI is normally hidden.

So my partitions are not longer messed up, removed all the weirdness the vendor did to them.  But still not finished, had to setup C: to boot correctly.  Tried `bcdedit /enum` and saw some odd boot settings in my C:, so to undo that `bcdboot C:\Windows /v`.  The last thing is the secret sauce.

At this point `bcdedit /enum` showed more normal looking things and it booted properly.

[image: Disk Management]

Above, that first 301MB unallocated was the original boot partition I deleted.